# Codeigniter Issue with class in helper module

Tags: php, codeigniter, class

I have an issue with my codeigniter helper.

This is my controler that calls a view:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('inc/header');
        $this->load->view('login_view');
        $this->load->view('inc/footer');
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I have more then one controler with multiple functions that can call a view.

so I thought I make a helper:

```
function view($site) {
    $this->load->view('inc/header');
    $this->load->view($site);
    $this->load->view('inc/footer');
}
```

When I call this helper like this:

```
view('login_view');
```

I get this error:

```
> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\.....\application\helpers\custom_helper.php on line 23
```

line 23 =

```
$this->load->view('inc/header');
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building helpers, you must use the get_instance function. This allows your function to use the CodeIgniter resources.

So, your function would look like this;

```
function view($site)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->load->view('inc/header');
    $CI->load->view($site);
    $CI->load->view('inc/footer');
}
```

**EDIT:**

You should also pass an array to this function, which will allow you to load data to the view. Like this;

```
function view($site, $data = array())
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $CI->load->view('inc/header', $data);
    $CI->load->view($site, $data);
    $CI->load->view('inc/footer', $data);
}
```

Comment: You should also pass an array through to the view function, for any dynamic data you want to pass to the view. I will update my answer with a new function to show you.